# Gradle error while running app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I was writing my code and didn't touch any files of the project.
Then i wanted to start the app again and it shows me this error :
'
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2/gradle-8.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2/gradle-8.2.pom
     Required by:
         project : '
```

I tried many solutions in many websites but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in Main project gradle file

```
dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
}
```

put this line in gradle-wrapper-properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you check your build.gradle file in android folder. At dependencies,
I think you added build tools as `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2'`, there is no 8.2 version. try it with 7.1.2

Comment: I fixed it, now it gives another error :
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug'.
      > Could not create task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
         > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

Comment: Check your android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties file. and replace distributionUrl with this. distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip

Comment: @Arminyouuu did you solve the `IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core()` issue?

Comment: @JayKoutavas Yes . I created a new project -_-

Comment: @Arminyouuu I ended-up doing the same. Created a new project and then compared the `build.gradle` file that was generated with my older `build.gradle` file.